# Getting Fatal error when refund method throw exception

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.3

I am getting below error when any exception throws in refund() method

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException::__construct() must be
>   an instance of Magento\Framework\Phrase, string given, called in
>   /vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Service/CreditmemoService.php on
>   line 185 and defined in
>   /vendor/magento/framework/Exception/LocalizedException.php on line 34

I know solution but this is core file so how can i handle above error.

Comment: This issue already fixed on develop branch and fix will be available in Magento 2.1.4 release.